# How to detect positive weight cycle by modifying floyd warshall algorithm?

Tags: shortest-path

In all pair shortest path, is there any way to detect positive weight cycle by modifying floyd warshall algorithm? if it is, how can we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if a node have positive weight after traversing all the nodes then there will be a positive cycle.

Answer (score 1):

One can do this by putting a check if a node is visited is again and again after traversing all the nodes. then it will be a positive cycle.